# Looking for an ESLint rule to enforce destructured function parameters to be sorted alphabetically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

in one of my projects we have an ESLint rule that enforces React props to be sorted alphabetically.

So:

```
// BAD:  
<Component
    bProp={​​​​​​/bla/}​​​​​​
    aProp={​​​​​​/bla/}​​​​​​
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
    Props should be sorted alphabetically -- eslint(react/jsx-sort-props)
/>

// GOOD:  
<Component
    aProp={​​​​​​​​/bla/}​​​​​​​​
    bProp={​​​​​​​/bla/}​​​​​​​
/>
```

Now I'm looking for a similar rule, only for destructured function parameters:

```
export const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({​​​​​​​
    bProp,
    aProp,
    ^^^^^^
    Destructured parameters should be sorted alphabetically ...
}​​​​​​​) => {​​​​​​​
// ...
```

Does anyone know of a rule like that? My googling wasn't successful.. :/

Comment: I couldn't find anything in eslint itself, but there is an [eslint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-sort-destructure-keys), although seemingly not maintained.

Comment: Awesome! Does exactly what I was looking for. Kudos to your googling skills, sir!